# Can we reset .requires_grad of all defined tensors in a code to zero at once

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I am using PyTorch 1.6.0 to learn a tensor (lets say x) with autograd.
After x is learnt, how can I reset .requires_grad of every tensor that was a node in the autograd comp. graph to zero?
I know about torch.detach() and about setting .requires_grad to False manually. I am searching for an one-shot instruction.

Ps: I want to do that because I still want to use these tensors after the part of my code that learns x is executed. Plus, some are to be converted to numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "one shot instruction" to switch `.requires_grad` for all tensors in graph.

Usually `parameters` are kept in `torch.nn.Module` instances but in case they are elsewhere, you can always add them to some `list` and iterate over it, I'd do something like this:

```
import torch


class Leafs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leafs = []

    def add(self, tensor):
        self.leafs.append(tensor)
        return tensor

    def clear(self):
        for leaf in self.leafs:
            leaf.requires_grad_(False)


keeper = Leafs()

x = keeper.add(torch.tensor([1.2], requires_grad=True))
y = keeper.add(torch.tensor([1.3], requires_grad=True))

print(x.requires_grad, y.requires_grad)

keeper.clear()

print(x.requires_grad, y.requires_grad)
```

Usually there is no need for that, also if you don't want gradient for some part of computation you can always use `with torch.no_grad()` context manager.